# Is there a video player that supports the orientation flag?

Tags: video, orientation

My camera takes videos that save the orientation of the video. I'd like to have them play with the correct orientation on my phone. Is there a player (paid or free) that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say all videos players, but in doubt I tested :

- AOSP Gallery : works.
- The new "Photos" app that comes with Google+ : works.
- [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) (free) : works.

Comment: I'm tested AOSP Gallery and MX Player: both ignore the orientation flag on videos. How are you getting them to work?

Comment: I recorded two videos with the aosp camera : one in portrait, one in landscape. Gallery and Photos don't switch the orientation automatically, MX Player does. (For MX player, I installed it just before the test and didn't go in the settings)

Comment: Hm. Okay. Thanks. I just discovered the "rotate" button in MX Player, so I will use that!